# Deming regression prediction interval using jackknife resampling

Tags: prediction-interval, total-least-squares, jackknife

I am trying to write a custom Deming function following the maths in Linnet (1993):

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2281234

Using jackknife resampling I calculate the standard error for the slope and intercept to allow me to create a confidence interval. First calculate pseudovalues:

$$ {\hat\theta}_i^* = N\hat\theta-(N-1)\hat\theta_{-i} $$

Then I can calculate the standard error of these pseudovalues and from that, calculate a confidence interval for the slope and intercept:

$$ s.e. = s\sqrt\frac{1}{n}$$

I can follow the same method where $\theta=\hat y$ i.e. a predicted value at some new $x$.

I have checked my methods against the `mcr`package in R. I obtain the same slope and intercept with their respective CIs and obtain the same predictions for new values of $x$ as well as their standard errors and CIs. I've tried to repeat the procedure using a prediction interval, calculating the standard error as such (note the $s$ refers to the standard deviation of the *pseudovalue estimates of $\hat y$*):

$$ s.e. = s\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$

When I do this I obtain an interval wider than the CI (green in the image) but shaped like a CI where I expected a near straight interval. Have I done something wrong? If I calculate a PI in the standard way one would for Simple Linear Regression, I do get a straight interval.

Finally, is there a package anyone can recommend that would do this so I could validate my results?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your second equation for se looks like an equation for CI. I have not seen a package that deals with prediction bounds, however, there is a software (excel add on) called analyse-it that provides prediction bounds for deming regression. Basically you will need either a value of lambda (ratio of residual variances in y and x) or individual estimates of such variances to derive prediction bounds.